# jquery double line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which reads the text from two TextArea inputs contained in a dialog box and inserts them into a multi-line asp textbox after I click the save button.

What I want is for the text from the variables sReason and sParents to appear with two empty rows between them.. ie:

```
text from sReason


text from sParents
```

Here is the code for my jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    $("#DiagSituation").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            "Save": function() {

            var sReason = "The reason I am informing/referring to you is " + $('#SitReason').val()
            var sParents = "Parent/s presented " + $('#SitParents').val()

                $('#txbRefConcern').val(sReason + " " + sParents);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                $('#SitReason').val("");
                $('#SitParents').val("");
            }
        });

        var txbRefCon = $("#txbRefConcern").val();
        if (jQuery.trim(txbRefCon).length == 0)    
            {
                $("#txbRefConcern").click(function() { $("#DiagSituation").dialog("open"); });
            }
    });
    </script>
```

I have tried editing the `$('#txbRefConcern').val(sReason + " " + sParents);` line of code and adding \ in the quotes but this hasn't worked. How can I get the additional line breaks? I am still new to coding in jquery/javascript so some example code with be helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something allong these lines:

```
$('#txbRefConcern').val(sReason + "\n\n\n" + sParents);
```

\n is the Newline character, \r is the windows variant if im correct (meaning carriage Return)

Comment: The `\r\n` combination also works. I used this when I did a JS project a while ago: http://jsfiddle.net/samuelmac/CpCCH/